# Tensorflow multiple parameter to function

Tags: tensorflow

While learning tensorflow, I am confused with code like:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
```

So I try to print the x:

```
print('x before', x)
x before Tensor("global_average_pooling2d_1/Mean:0", shape=(None, 1280), dtype=float32)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
print('x after', x)
x after Tensor("dropout/cond/Identity:0", shape=(None, 1280), dtype=float32)
```

My understanding is: 0.2 is the parameter to the function, but what is this (x) syntax?

Any reference would be appreicated

Comment: You create a layer with the call to Dropout(0.2), and that layer is callable to add it to your graph. So afterwards x is the output of the dropout layouer, and the original x is the input.

Comment: https://keras.io/api/layers/ the very first example describes it. you pass the input to the argument of the layer you create.